# ActiveAdmin :date_range filter type causes undefined_method error (MetaSearch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, activeadmin, meta-search

I am implementing ActiveAdmin and would like to use the `:date_range` filter type on my Job table's date column. According to the documentation this just needs to be set as `filter [:attr], :as => :date_range`. When I use this code I get the following error:

```
undefined method `when_datetime_gte' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Job:0xda5b68c>
```

Searching this error in Google produces absolutely *nothing*! I am using version 0.6.3 of ActiveAdmin and have `gem "meta_search",  '>= 1.1.0.pre'` for MetaSearch in my `Gemfile` per the ActiveAdmin docs.

Any idea what's going on??

Answer (score 0):

If your model/resource includes a date attribute (when_datetime), you only need to add the following snippet of code to your page:

```
filter :when_datetime
```

if the `when_datetime` has a date type, the filter is going to be a `date_range` by default.

Comment: You're right, normally it would be that easy. This question is no longer relevant but I think the problem was that the date was being stored as a string (`"MM/DD/YY"`) and I was trying to get AA to recognize it as a date, hence my use of `filter...as`. I should've made that more clear in the original question.